# What can be assigned in bool and DateTime variables in case of null?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
DataTable rdrFeedback;
using (rdrFeedback = CommonHelper.GetDataTable(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[Crew].[Up_CM_SEAFARER_FEEDBACK]", sqlParams.ToArray()))
{
    foreach(DataRow dRow in rdrFeedback.Rows)
    {
            bool? AnswSix = dRow["ANSW_SIX"] != DBNull.Value ? (bool)dRow["ANSW_SIX"] : DBNull.Value; 
            DateTime? AcknowledgedOn = dRow["ACKNOWLEDGED_ON"] != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToDateTime(dRow["ACKNOWLEDGED_ON"].ToString()) : null;
    }
}
```

Above statement gives this errors while fetching data from stored procedure:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between
>   'bool' and 'System.DBNull'.
>
> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between
>   'DateTime' and 'null'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a cast to `DateTime?` from `DateTime`

```
DateTime? AcknowledgedOn = dRow["ACKNOWLEDGED_ON"] != DBNull.Value 
   ? (DateTime?) Convert.ToDateTime(dRow["ACKNOWLEDGED_ON"].ToString()) 
   : null;
```

The same is true for `bool` but you have to specify `null` as the alternate value not `DBNull.Value`.

```
bool? AnswSix = dRow["ANSW_SIX"] != DBNull.Value 
  ? (bool?)dRow["ANSW_SIX"] 
  : null;
```

Also why are you using `Convert.ToDateTime`? If your database has a date time value it should be:

1. Stored as an actual `Date` or `DateTime` type in the database
2. Retrieved as a `DateTime` type

Do not store `DateTime` instances as strings and do not retrieve them as strings.